# ffmpeg incorrectly adds a fixed delay to the end of each video chunk

Tags: video, ffmpeg, synchronization

I am trying to combine audio a video data to output as an mp4 file using the command below, the videos are segmented to match the exact length of the audio file they are going to be merged with:

```
    command = 'ffmpeg -y -i {} -i {} -strict -2 -q:v 1 {} -loglevel {} -c:v h264_nvenc'.format(
        audio_file, temp_result_avi, outfile, self.ffmpeg_loglevel
    )
    subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

however each video made by this is exactly 24 ms longer so this causes large delays as they get stitched back together. This doesnt work since the combined video needs to be combined back with another video and the desync gets worse as you get further in the combined videos.

How can I remedy this?

Comment: Save to MOV and audio codec pcm_s16le and only convert to AAC in final concat step.